# Удалить метку "определние", оставить "определение"

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено

Удалить метку "определние", оставить "определение". Если невозможно удалить, сделать ее синонимом "запрещенной метки". Было два вопроса, ассоциированные с ней, я перевел их на метку "определение".

Comment: М_Г, прошу прощения за то, что долго не отвечал. Постараюсь исправиться!

Answer (score 1):

Синонимы были созданы. Спасибо за помощь!